# will an atomic variable in if statement protect the if body?

Tags: c++

For example:

```
#include <atomic>

std::atomic_bool atomicBool(false);
int sharedVariable = 0;

void work() {
  if (atomicBool) {
    sharedVariable++; //will this line protected by atomic variable?
  }
}
```

will the statement `sharedVariable++;` protected to be thread safe by the `atomicBool`?
If not (as a glimpse of the file I guess not), does that mean is this case I still need to use the mutex lock?

Comment: Atomic variables do not "protect" anything. Neither do they do much inter-thread sequencing. Most attempts to use atomic variables in a quest for the lock-free fairy eventually end in tears.

Comment: `will this line protected by atomic variable?` Protected from what?

Comment: Only if your program is not multithreaded.

Comment: @Eljay Just because no protection is required doesn't mean protection is magically given ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [atomic<bool> vs bool protected by mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38146681/atomicbool-vs-bool-protected-by-mutex)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No.**

Atomic variables are not mutexes.

They do not protect anything except reads and writes to themselves.

Even if they did, with this syntax, there is no way for the variable to "know" about the scope it's been named in.

It sounds like perhaps `sharedVariable` should be the atomic, though that is again not sufficient if you have *more* statements to protect as a block in your real code.

Answer (score 3):

As the other answers have said, no, it is not protected in any meaningful way. What this answer adds is a concrete example.

I am assuming by "protect", you mean that you want to stop `sharedVariable` from being caught up in a race condition and undefined behaviour ensuing. For this to make sense, I am going to assume that you actually set `atomicBool` somewhere.

With that in mind, here's an example scenario of why your atomic is not sufficient:

1. `atomicBool` is read by thread 1. It is `true`.
2. `atomicBool` is read by thread 2. It is `true`.
3. Both threads now attempt to change `sharedVariable`. This is a race condition!

Now suppose you set the atomic variable inside of the if statement like so:

```
if (atomicBool) {
    atomicBool = false;
    sharedVariable++;
}
```

This has a race condition of its own, here's an example of how it may occur:

1. `atomicBool` is read by thread 1. It is `true`.
2. `atomicBool` is read by thread 2. It is `true`.
3. `atomicBool` is written by thread 1 to `false`.
4. `atomicBool` is written by thread 2 to `false`.
5. Both threads now attempt to change `sharedVariable`. This is a race condition!

There are "compare and change" / "test and set" checks you can use instead that do this atomically (i.e. the check and the write appear to happen at the same time for all observers).

Mutexes can help solve this problem, making the variable you want to change atomic can solve this problem, but it's hard to say which is more appropriate and whether or not you'll introduce more race conditions in the process without more context.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not protect the modification. Yes, you need to use mutex in such case, or make `sharedVariable` itself atomic.